# How can I add an ip_restriction block to Terraform Azure Function App site_config?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, terraform

I have created an Azure Function App using Terraform and I now want to add some IP Restrictions to the function app but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

The **site_config** block accepts an **ip_restriction** list of objects, in my example I'm using just one.  The **ip_restriction** 'type' can be either **ipaddress**, **service_tag** or **virtual_network_subnet_id**.  You can only specify one type per ip_restriction.

After trying various ways to set out the syntax I eventually created a function app & then set the IP Restrictions manually and then had a look at the JSON of the object in Azure.  Armed (get it?) with that information I tried to add the same options to my Terraform code like this:

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
  name                       = "ssc-dom-test-fnap01"
  location                   = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name        = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  app_service_plan_id        = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  version                    = "~3"

  site_config {
    ip_restriction = [
     {
       "action": "Allow",
       "headers": [],
       "ip_address": "",
       "name": "AzureCloudIn",
       "priority": 102,
       "service_tag": "AzureCloud",
       "virtual_network_subnet_id": ""
     }
    ]
  }
}
```

But, if I now run `terraform validate` I get errors saying:

```
│
│   with azurerm_function_app.example,
│   on main.tf line 34, in resource "azurerm_function_app" "example":
│   34:   site_config {
│
╵
╷
│ Error: expected "site_config.0.ip_restriction.0.ip_address" to not be an empty string, got 
│
│   with azurerm_function_app.example,
│   on main.tf line 34, in resource "azurerm_function_app" "example":
│   34:   site_config {
```

I have tried commenting out the ip_address and virtual_network_subnet_id options and removing them completely but I can't get a syntax that will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
resource "azurerm_function_app" "example" {
name = "ssc-dom-fnap-001"
location = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
storage_account_name = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
version = "~3"

site_config {
ip_restriction {
ip_address = "62.255.234.81/32"
priority = 100
name = "SCTS Access Only"
}

}
}
```

That's the syntax there basically

Comment: Thanks Gabriel - that has solved my problem!  And, as you can see from below I can add a different type of ip_restriction to the block easily too:
```site_config {
    ip_restriction {
      ip_address = "62.255.234.81/32"
      priority   = 100
      name       = "SCTS Access Only"
    }

    ip_restriction {
      service_tag = "AzureCloud"
      priority    = 102
      name        = "AzureCloudIn"
    }

  }```